# Re-saving a model instance in Django not working, but update() does work

Tags: python, django, django-models

Going a bit crazy with something that stopped working in my Django app (Django 3.2.5, Python 3.9.6) - here's a simplified version:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  attribute_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='0')

myModel = MyModel()
myModel.save()
print(myModel.attribute_1) # OUTPUTS '0'


myModel.attribute_1 = '1' # EDITED MY TYPO HERE...
myModel.save()
print(myModel.attribute_1) # OUTPUTS '1'
```

The second `save()` is not being saved, if I retrieve `myModel` from the database elsewhere I get `attribute_1` equal to `0`.

This, however, does work as I expect it to:

```
myModel = MyModel()
myModel.save()
MyModel.filter(pk=myModel.pk).update(attribute_1='1')
```

Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: if you have a master-slave configuration then you might be reading from the slave and writing to the master.

Comment: @VishalSingh thanks but no it is not a master/slave. There is a cache, however, flushing the cache still does not result in the save taking place.

Answer (score 3):

To set the attribute of your model instance you need to assign a new value to the attribute (field) you want to change;

```
# instead of
myModel(attribute_1='1')

# you'd do
myModel.attribute_1 = '1'
myModel.save()

# You could also use a more efficient save
myModel.save(update_fields=['attribute_1'])
```

If you're modifying objects like this you might also need to get the latest version from the database using [`refresh_from_db()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)

```
myModel.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Thanks - sorry that is my type in the code.

Comment: Fixed - the update_fields doesn't change the behaviour - will try the refresh_from_db() but why would that be necessary?

Comment: @tunecrew it's not necessary, but good to learn about these things

Comment: thanks @markwalker_ but the original question remains - it should save again as expected.